# testing recurring payments using cmd=_xclick-subscriptions

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I've got a form which is automatically submitted to paypal. If someone signs up for a recurring subscription, the following fields are added to the form:

```
cmd=_xclick-subscriptions
a3=(dollar amount)
p3= (billing frequency)
t3= (billing period)
```

p3 and t3 are always 1 and M (once every month). Read a paypal document which said changing that to once every day would actually force the recurring payments to happen every minute instead of day. I tried doing this but it's not rebilling every minute.

Is there something else i have to do in order to trigger a recurring payment?

Answer (score 0):

In t3 here M stands for month not for minute, so t3=M and p3=1 means every month.

Comment: This was a while ago - i believe this was using the paypal sandbox test account.